# Banach-Tarski-like Paradox

Tags: measure-theory, paradoxes

This is Problem 9 of Chapter 1 of Stein and Shakarchi's *Functional Analysis*.

> As a consequence of the previous problem one can show that it is not possible to extend Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ , $d \ge 3$, as a finitely-additive measure on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ so that it is both translation and rotation invariant (that is, invariant under Euclidean motions). This is graphically shown by the “Banach-Tarski paradox”: There is a ﬁnite decomposition of the unit ball $B_1 = \sum_{j=1}^N E_j$, with the sets $E_j$ disjoint, and there are corresponding sets $\tilde{E}_j$ that are each obtained from $E_j$ by a Euclidean motion, with the $\tilde{E}_j$ also disjoint, so that $\sum_{j=1}^N \tilde{E}_j = B_2$ the ball of radius 2.

The "previous problem" refers to the [Hausdorff Paradox](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_Paradox).

The Banach-Tarski paradox, as far as I know, is a proof the a unit ball can be doubled into two unit balls through rotations of its component sets. But this problem is about doubling the radius of the unit ball through rotations and translations.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: The [strong form of the Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox), which is what Banach and Tarski proved, is more general: you can partition any two bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ with nonempty interiors into finite subsets which are pairwise congruent.  Both the "unit ball to two unit balls" and "unit ball to radius-2 ball" paradoxes are examples of this.

Comment: Ane the general result can be derived from the "one ball into two" result. E.g., from the theorem that  a unit ball is "equivalent by finite decomposition" to the union of two disjoint unit balls, it follows by induction that a unit ball is equivalent b.f.d. to the union of any finite number of disjoint unit balls. A large ball (of radius two, say) can be cut up into some number $N$ of pieces, each of which can be packed into a unit ball; therefore the large ball is equivalent b.f.d. to a subset of the unit ball, and vice versa, the unit ball to a subset of the large ball. To conclude you need

Comment: an improved version of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem (sometimes called Banach's mapping theorem) which says that, given injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, we can construct a bijection $h:A\to B$ such that $h\subseteq f\cup g^{-1}$.